# Difference between hardhat scripts and hardhat-deploy?

Tags: contract-development, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I've been developing smart contracts for a while using `truffle` but this is my first `hardhat` project. I'm trying to wrap my head around the best practices for testing/developing on my local machine but also deploying to actual blockchains.

The [Hardhat Docs](https://hardhat.org/guides/deploying.html) suggest using the `hardhat-deploy` plugin to deploy smart contract. To setup my project, I followed the [Quick Start Guide](https://hardhat.org/getting-started/#quick-start) which outlines deploying contracts via functions in the `scripts` folder.

Before I delve too deep into this, can someone help me understand the different use cases between the `scripts` folder and the `deploy` folder that `hardhat-deploy` uses? Does `deploy` supercede `scripts`, or would there still be reasons to create scripts?

Comment: scripts is generic. Any and all of your scripts should go in there. Before hardhat-deploy, deploy scripts would also go there. `hardhat-deploy` was created to remove the need to remember which contracts were deployed. It automatically deploys all of the scripts in the `deploy` folder intelligently (not redeploying those already deployed, etc.) for you.